# discrete subgroups of euclidean space

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm trying to prove this proposition:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_discrete_subgroup_of_Euclidean_space_is_free_Abelian_on_a_linearly_independent_set

That every discrete subgroup of Euclidean space is free Abelian with rank at most n, but I don't know how to approach it, even with the "used facts" section.

Any help please?

Comment: I think that exercise 31 chapter 5 of Markus *Number Fields* can help you

Answer (score 4):

Let $h\in H$ since $h+h+...+h\in H$ this means that $h\mathbb{Z}\subset H$. Now assume there are at most $k\leq n$ linearly independant (over the reals) $h_i\in H$. This means that $H$ contains the lattice generated by them which is a discrete abelien subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and has rank $k$.

Since we assumed $H$ has only $k$ linearly independat vectors that means that $H$ spans a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which for simplicity we shall denote by $\mathbb{R}^k$.

So we have a full lattice $L \subset H \subset \mathbb{R}^k$.

We need to show that $H$ is also a lattice. This would mean it has $k$ generators and therefore rank $k$.

That would need to show that the index $|H:L|$ is finite.

Now let is notice that we can represent any vector $h\in H$ as $h=l+p$ for $l\in L$ and $p=(a_1h_1,...,a_kh_k)$ for $a_i\in [0,1)$ (the set $P$ of such points $p$ is called the fundamental parallelepiped of a lattice).

Now since $H$ is a group $p\in H$.

$P$ however is bounded and $H$ is discrete therefore there can only be finitely many elements $p\in P$ which are also in $H$.

This means that $\forall p\in H \exists i_p: i_pp\in H$. Let $j$ the least common multiple.

This means that $H$ is contained in the lattice generated by $\frac{h_i}{j}$.

Hence $H$ is a lattice and has rank $k$.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify @Mr.P's answer, to prove $|H:L|$ is finite we can also note that $\mathbb{R}^k/L \cong \prod_{i=1}^k S^1$. The image of $H$ in the quotient is still discrete, and it's a subgroup of the right hand side, which is compact, so $d := |H:L|<\infty$.

Then, for any $x\in H$, $dx + L = d(x+L) = L$ because the order is $d$, so $dx \in L$, which means $dH \subseteq L$ (i.e. H is generated by $h_i/d$).